# Search module: re-indexing

Tags: drupal, search, drupal-6

I've noticed the search engine is drupal sometimes requires to be re-indexed in order to update its index with latest posts.

I was wondering how often the re-indexing is performed, and if it is automatically performed by default.

Is it triggered by cron process ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-indexing is sort of a misnomer. In Drupal, re-indexing a site means clearing out the current index and re-doing the entire index. This is only done manually, from admin/settings/search.

Using cron, Drupal will add new and updated nodes to the existing index: it doesn't re-index the site every time cron runs.

Drupal's index update only occurs during a cron run. Either go to http://example.com/cron.php or run it from the Status report page at admin/reports/status.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it triggered by cron process ?

Yes

Answer (score 1):

Cron reindexes your site as often as you tell it to run, but you can always do it manually as well at yoursite/admin/settings/search.